# CSS position fixed some ; i want it to be at absolute bottom and body to be just above it

Tags: html, css, drupal

I positioned a div at the bottom, but the last part of the body disappears. How do I fix this?

```
    #fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top: 95%;
    height:2em;
    left: 0px;
    display:block;
    color: #F0F8FF;
    background-color:#00008B;
    }
    <body>
    <div id="fixed">
    Login Login
    </div>
    <dv id="content-box">
    <p>KAKAK</p>
    <p>KAKAK</p><p>KAKAK</p>
    <p>KAKAK</p>
    <p>KAKAK1</p>
    <p>KAKAK2</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Paste the relevant html and css code and we'll figure out what's going on. The more specific you are, the more we can help. :)

Comment: HTML is just a spam though :P but i still added it. Check out

Comment: you removed some of those paragraphs so it works fine when u have all of those the last one gets a bit hided under the element :/

Comment: I added the paragraphs and edited my answer, let me know if it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give bottom padding to the body equal to the height of the div.

```
body{
    padding-bottom:2em;
}
```

but you also have to change in your code the `top: 95%;` to `bottom:0;` in the `#fixed` rule, because the height is not known so the remaining `5%` might be less than the `2em` height of the div (*it causes the div to move outside of the body ..*).

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cvxtk/1/

Comment: Can u give the code because when i added the bottom padding using padding-bottom this doesnt seems to work the html is placed above

Comment: Works fine :D Thanks. And thanks for telling that website too :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the fixed div at the bottom and specify 95% for the top, like so:

```
<body>
    <body>
    <div id="content-box">
    <p>KAKAK</p>
    <p>KAKAK1</p>
    <p>KAKAK2</p>
    </div>
        <div id="fixed">
    Login Login
    </div>

    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Add css info for the content div so it looks something like this:

```
#fixed {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
top:95%;
bottom:0px;
height:2em;
left:0px;
display:block;
color:#F0F8FF;
background-color:#00008B;
}

#content-box {
padding-bottom: 20em;
}
```

Comment: Nope a part of it is still hidden

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. What do you think now? You can change the 20em in the #content-box div to a larger or smaller number depending on how much space you want.

Comment: try to change the **top:95%** to **bottom: 0px**